# Unable to filter on an Instance TAG for describe instance status in boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

This is what I am looking to achieve -
I would like to get a total instance count for all instances whose "instance-status.reachability" status is set to "passed" + I am only interested in instances with a particular tag name.

I am able to filter on instance-status.reachability but unable to filter on the TAG

```
 instancesWithInitializingStatus = client.describe_instance_status(

                Filters=[
                    {
                        'Name': 'instance-status.reachability',
                        'Values': ['passed']
                    },
                    {
                        'Name': 'tag:LoadTestName', 
                        'Values': ['Jan11_tds-session2-remote-longrun-withloop_1000_202946']
                    }
                ],
)
```

This is the ERROR I get

```
Unexpected error : An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DescribeInstanceStatus operation: The filter 'tag:LoadTestName' is invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

[describe_instance_status](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status) **does not support** tag-based filters. Instead [describe_instances](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instances) supports them.

Therefore, you have to first use `describe_instances` to get instances Ids with your tags, and then pass these Ids into `describe_instance_status`.